# perl application won't start in apache when running as a service

Tags: linux, security, centos6

I have installed Netdisco, which is a perl based network discovery tool

When I run httpd from a terminal prompt as root, it works fine.

When I try and start Apache as a service (service httpd start), I get the following error(s):

```
Starting httpd: [Mon Apr 23 19:45:48 2012] [warn] module perl_module is already loaded, skipping
[Mon Apr 23 19:45:48 2012] [warn] module apreq_module is already loaded, skipping
Syntax error on line 22 of /etc/httpd/conf/netdisco_apache.conf:
Can't locate netdisco.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/netdisco /usr/local/lib/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 . /etc/httpd) at /etc/httpd/conf/netdisco_apache.conf line 26.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted\t(in cleanup) Can't locate netdisco.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/netdisco /usr/local/lib/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 . /etc/httpd) at /etc/httpd/conf/netdisco_apache.conf line 26.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /etc/httpd/conf/netdisco_apache.conf line 26.\n
```

I tried adding the apache user to the netdisco group netdisco, and got the same result.

netdisco.pm is definitely in the first folder in @INC (/usr/local/netdisco), and the netdisco user / group owns that folder and all files, including netdisco.pm

Why won't it start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that apache user has execute access to the /usr/local/netdisco folder and read access for the /usr/local/netdisco/netdisco.pm file.

You can also `strace` the startup of apache to find which files is trying to access. If those files exists it is a permission problem. Besides the Unix permissions you have to check the SELinux configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do have a question: if the apache user is a member of the netdisco group, it gets all the permissions that the group has, correct?

Comment: Yes, it does, except SELinux ones. If SE linux is disabled or permisive, you can su as the apache user and try to see if you have access to the required file.

Comment: Thanks Mircea, it is definitely permissions related. I can see this from the strace output:  5101  stat64("/usr/local/netdisco", 0x15aeeb0) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)       Now the question is, how do I configure the apache user to have access to /usr/local/netdisco?   That folder is owned by the netdisco group, and the apache user is a member of that group.

Comment: my selinux is in enforcing mode. Is it accurate to say that selinux is restricting what the apache user can access?  Where can I change the allowed access for the apache user?

Comment: First make sure that the group has execute access on the `/usr/local/netdisco` folder. E.g. the folder has `drwx--x---` (most restrictive) or `drwxr-xr-x` permissions. Run `chgrp netdisco /usr/local/netdisco;chmod g+x /usr/local/netdisco`.

Comment: If this does not help you have to relabel the folder. See: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-fsrelabel.html and http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

Comment: Awesome, thanks Mircea. Have an "answered" :-)

Comment: So what was the problem?

Comment: It was the selinux. I went to the links you gave and saw how to change it, figured it was too much hassle and changed my selinux policy to disabled :-)  After a reboot, the httpd started right up and netdisco worked as expected

Comment: For security reasons you should keep SELinux. You can configure it to be enabled, but not enforced (permissive). This will allow you to test the changes and see if they are ok without disrupting the availability. Then when you have no more SELinux exceptions, you can enable it.